# SyntaxError with dict()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax-error

When I try to create this

```
self.cmds = {
             'help' : self.cmdsHelp,
             'write-start' : self.startWriter,
             'write' : self.writeTo,
             'read-start' : self.startReader,
             'read' : self.readFrom
            }
```

with the built-in `dict()` function... i.e.

```
self.cmds = dict(
                 help = self.cmdsHelp,
                 write-start = self.startWriter,
                 write = self.writeTo,
                 read-start = self.startReader,
                 read = self.readFrom
                )
```

... I get this error:

```
    write-start = self.startWriter,
                            ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

The dictionary with the curly brackets (`{}`) -- whatever special name that is -- works, but I cannot fathom why the "newer version" (the `dict()` form) does not work. Is there something that I am missing, or do you just have to use the curly braces?

#### For clarity:

Each value in the dictionary is a function (and yes I did remove `self.`, and I also tried to do both `self.function()` and `function()` so that when I called it I didn't have to do `self.cmds[<input>]()` but could rather do `self.cmds[<input>]`)

Comment: While `dict(keyword=value)` may be "newer", you're still talking about Python 2.3, which is pretty ancient. And what makes you think it's in any way better? It compiles to larger code, and be slower, and, worse of all, it's more limited (as you've seen here). If it makes your code more readable somewhere, sure, use it, but there is no reason to avoid dict displays.

Comment: Oh, the thing with the curly braces is officially called a ["dictionary display"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dict), but as of 2.7 and 3.0 a dict comprehension is _also_ called a dictionary display, which can be confusing, so a lot of people still say "dictionary literal" (the name in early 2.x) in place of "dictionary display that isn't a comprehension" or "dictionary display with comma-separated key-datum pairs" or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keyword arguments **must** be [valid python identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). You cannot use `-` in valid identifiers (you are trying to subtract two identifiers instead). `dict()` is just a callable, and keyword arguments passed to it are no exception.

Use the `{}` literal dict syntax instead:

```
self.cmds = {
    'help': self.cmdsHelp,
    'write-start': self.startWriter,
    'write': self.writeTo,
    'read-start': self.startReader,
    'read': self.readFrom,
}
```

because then you can use any valid immutable & hashable value as keys.

Alternatively, use valid identifiers; replace `-` with `_`, a character that *is* allowed in indentifiers:

```
self.cmds = dict(
    help=self.cmdsHelp,
    write_start=self.startWriter,
    write=self.writeTo,
    read_start=self.startReader,
    read=self.readFrom,
)
```

Any other alternatives get ugly real fast; you could use the dict literal syntax to produce a `**kwargs` double-splat keyword argument mapping:

```
self.cmds = dict(
    help=self.cmdsHelp,
    write=self.writeTo,
    read=self.readFrom,
    **{
        'read-start': self.startReader,
        'write-start': self.startWriter,
    }
)
```

but that's not any more readable, is it.

You can set those peskey non-identifier keys after the fact:

```
self.cmds = dict(
    help=self.cmdsHelp,
    write=self.writeTo,
    read=self.readFrom,
)
self.cmds['read-start'] = self.startReader
self.cmds['write-start'] = self.startWriter
```

but that's more ugly still.

Note that dictionary displays (the [official term for the syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays)) are *faster* for the interpreter to process than are `dict()` calls, as fewer bytecode instructions are used to build one and no function call is involved.

Comment: I think you forgot some colons.

Comment: So, There isn't a way to do it with `dict()`, then?

Comment: ... if I want to use the `-`?

Comment: @Dylan: Well, sure, there's a way to do it with `dict`: just pass it an iterable of key-value tuples instead of passing it a bunch of keyword arguments. But that's going to look a lot uglier than just writing a dict literal, so I'm not sure why you'd want to…

Comment: @Dylan: you can work around the limitation by passing in keyword arguments using the  `**dictobj` syntax. Which requires you to create a dictionary by other means. A catch 22!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Wait, you could construct that other dictionary from a dict comprehension around a keyword-initialized `dict` that used reversibly-cleaned-up names; you'd still have to type `write_start` in your initializer, but you'd end up with `write-start` in the actual dictionary. :)

Comment: One more crazy idea: If you just don't want to type the quotes around the keyword names, http://pastebin.com/pK3d4G7v is always an option. :)

Comment: @abarnert: LOL! Yeah, lets obfuscate the code some more!

Comment: Haha! It's fine; it's really just easier to do `dctnry = {'write-start' : self.startWriter}`. It's not like I absolutely need to write it with the `dict()` function. Great ideas, though. I particularly like the one about reformatting the key passed in. A little over my head for Python. The [hyphenizer class](http://pastebin.com/pK3d4G7v) is pretty clever, too.